# invalid argument trying to register a service worker in microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, service-worker

I am facing issue to register service worker in microsoft edge, while it successfully registered on other browser. It also unable to register service worker for other websites as well. Can you please suggest me window or edge settings, so i can allow it to register service worker.

I tried below code to register service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/lp_sw.js').then(function (reg) {
    console.log('[SW] Service worker has been registered'); 
}, function (e) { 
    console.error(e); 
});
```

The error I got for this is: "InvalidArgument"

It should show "[SW] Service worker has been registered" in console.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if service worker is available for those Edge browsers.

(1)After my experiment, if cookies are blocked, some web sites' service workers will also be rejected.

**Steps: Use Settings on edge>Advanced settings>Choose View advanced settings>Cookies>Choose Don't block cookies.**

[image]

(2)Enable Server Worker in Edge.

**Steps:Open Edge and type in the address bar `about:flags`>Standards Preview>Enable Server Worker>Choose Always On.**

[image]

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou, thanks for reply, Cookies a;lready enabled for browser and service worker option is not available there. You can check screenshot https://nimb.ws/L4y2vD

Comment: I think it's due to the different version of edge. My edge version is 42.17134.1.0, but your version is higher than mine, so it is strange that service worker not working on your side. Is there something wrong with your edge browser? If there is, you can try to repair, reset or reinstall it to default settings in Windows 10.

Comment: @YuZhou everything is permitted still getting the same error , do you have any idea  ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a feature inside the service worker that is not available in Edge? Because in my case I was using [BroadcastChannel which is not available yet in Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=broadcastchannel) so I got the same error.

I fixed it by checking first:

```
let myBroadcastChannel;
if (self.BroadcastChannel) {
  myBroadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('app-channel');
}
```

So it registered successfully, obviously without that feature.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. How did you figure out this was the case? Can it be retraced somehow by the error message or did you just experiment with disabling features in your code?

Comment: @wirher I don't remember exactly which the error message was, but I think that it was related yes. Then after reading a little bit about the BroadcastChannel API I found out. Luckily new chromium based Edge supports it.